# Tar using progress bar and handling multi-volumes

Tags: linux, bash, tar, progress-bar

I'm trying to create a tar of a large LVM volume onto multiple external drives.  That part is solved.  Now, because it is a LONG process, I'd like a progress bar.  From the excellent articles here, I've gotten close.

The issue is that the PV bar quits after the first volume fills up.  I'd like PV to continue updating after disks are swapped.  Does someone have an idea about how to approach this?

Here's what I've tried.  I think the problem is in the last line of code.  I'm not sure this strategy will actually work with multi-volumes.

Code ExtBackup.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

changedisk()
{
# This routine is called when tar runs out of disk space
# It simply waits for operator to change and mount disks
# then updates the file handle with a new volume number.
echo "Change disks now!" 
read -p "Press <enter> when new disk is mounted. ..." NULL
echo ""

# Update the file name with the new volume number
name=`expr $TAR_ARCHIVE : '\(.*\)-.*'`
echo ${name:-$TAR_ARCHIVE}-Vol$TAR_VOLUME.tar >&$TAR_FD
}

###########
## MAIN  ##
###########

# Test for recursive call to change disks
if [ "$1" = 'changedisk' ]; then 
        changedisk
        exit 0;
fi

# If this is initial call, set SIZE to calculate bytes in source    
SIZE=`du -sb *Folder_Name* | cut -f 1`

# Now TAR it, using Multi-volume option and pipe through PV for progress bar
tar -cM -F 'sh ExtBackup.sh changedisk' *Folder_Name* | \
pv -s ${SIZE} > LVMBackup-$(date +%m-%d-%y)-Vol1.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it took me some time to understand what `tar -F` actually does (is that documented anywhere at all? I just ended up reading the source), but I think I came up with a pretty good solution for you.

Since `pv` doesn't support pretending that a certain progress has already been made, I needed to replace it with a similar tool called `bar` (available in Debian under that name, or see its hideous [homepage](http://clpbar.sourceforge.net/)).

The solution I found passes the data of all additional volumes through a named pipe (FIFO) to inject the `bar` invocation into the stream. To avoid printing each volume's progress bar in a new line, I use 'tput' to move the cursor back up after each volume.

In your code, you would replace the last line in `changedisk()` with the following.
(This is a bit hacky for the sake of brevity; just customize it once you get the idea)

```bsh
tput cuu1 >&2 # clear previous progress bar
(cat somefifo | bar -ns \
    --size "$SIZE" \
    --completed $(((${TAR_VOLUME}-1)*${VOLSIZE})) \
    > ${name:-$TAR_ARCHIVE}-Vol$TAR_VOLUME.tar) &
echo somefifo >&$TAR_FD
```

And replace the `pv` invocation in the last line of your script with `bar -ns --size ${SIZE}`.

For this to work, you need to put `export` in front of the SIZE definition, and of course have executed `mkfifo somefifo` at some point beforehand. Make sure you also secure that FIFO's permission bits. You might also want to consider using `mktemp` to safely create a temporary pipe instead. Depends on your scenario, I guess.

I used an as-of-yet undefined variable `$VOLSIZE` that should expand to the size of your volumes in bytes. I'm not sure how this is determined in your setup. Maybe you need to do something more elaborate here, like keeping track of the cumulative sum of all the previous volume sizes.

Comment: The `-F` option aka. `--info-script` or `--new-volume-script` is well-documented on the [GNU manual page here][1] for the `tar` binary under **Section 9.6.1 (Archives Longer than One Tape or Disk)**.


  [1]: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Multi_002dVolume-Archives.html

Comment: True! Back in 2014, pre version 1.28, the manpage apparently was generated based on the CLI usage help and did not contain any further explanation of the option. The manual did provide more info at that time already, though.